# Three.js - "Unknown format" Error when using .FBX Models

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, fbx

im fairly new to THREE.js. Im trying to load a .FBX Object via the FBXLoader located in three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.
Also, i'm using this in React.js.

Now, the page loads but the model isnt there. The error in the console says: **An error happened: Error: THREE.FBXLoader: Unknown format.**

My FBX File seems to be in binary format, not in ASCII Format.
I really dont know what to do.

My Code:
//deleted

I also tried moving the models folder in and out of the public folder.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the FBX asset in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 Sorry, can't share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
My FBX file had an old version, also it had Binary encoding.
Switching to ASCII and a newer version fixed everything.